# Error finding templates by title

Tags: 2010, powershell, site-template

I have the following code to create a site and apply a custom template. It is working in my test environment that is created by backup-restore from my production portal.

This is the current script, based on the feedback in the comments:

```
#creates a site under the given url, based on the given template and title
Function CreateSite($parentUrl, $SubSiteUrl, $Template, $Title) {
    try {
        write-host "Read parent site"    
        $web = GET-SPWeb $parentUrl
        write-host "reading template"
        $wtemplate = $web.GetAvailableWebTemplates(1033) | Where-Object {$_.Title -eq $Template}   

        $url = $parentUrl + "/" + $SubSiteUrl
        write-host "creating site"
        $NewWeb = New-SPWeb -Url $url -Name $Title -UseParentTopNav
        $web = GET-SPWeb $url
        write-host "applying template"
        #System.Object[]
        $NewWeb.ApplyWebTemplate($wtemplate.Name)
        write-host "done"
        return "OK"

    }
                catch {

                $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
                if ($ErrorMessage -match 'is already in use.') {
               try{
             write-host "site exists, applying template"
               $web = GET-SPWeb $url
               $web.ApplyWebTemplate($wtemplate.Name)
             return "OK"
               }
               catch{
               $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
                 write-host $ErrorMessage
                return ($ErrorMessage)
               } 

                }

                write-host $ErrorMessage
                return ($ErrorMessage)
    }

    }
```

However, when I run it in my PRD server, I get the following error message on some of my sites:

> Exception calling "ApplyWebTemplate" with "1" argument(s): "File or
>   arguments not valid for site template 'System.Object[]'.

**Update:** Looks like we have double templates with the same title, but different names. However, these extra templates are not visible under "solutions" or in Designer, onder site templates like:

```
Name                                                Title
{A248FF57-5248-4C8B-9459-1B62703DACCD}#Customers    Customers
{CC69A307-7F92-47A7-8B6F-3981B480F9EA}#Customers    Customers
```

So, the task is to remove one of these templates, but I did not find any code that removes a web template by name. The Uninstall-SPSolution accepts the wsp file name as parameter, but there is only one customer.wsp in the solutions library, so this will probably remove both. Deactivating, removing and uploading template to the solution library didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add `.Name` at this line

```
$Web.ApplyWebTemplate($wtemplate.Name)
```

**Web.ApplyWebTemplate** method has one argument that is the web template **Name**

---

**[Update]**

I modified your script and tried it on my side, it should be now working properly!

```
$parentUrl = "http://epm:19812"
$SubSiteUrl = "Qassas2019"
$tempname = "Test"
$web = GET-SPWeb $parentUrl
$wtemplate = $web.GetAvailableWebTemplates(1033) | Where-Object {$_.Title -eq $tempname}   
$url = $parentUrl + "/" + $SubSiteUrl
$NewWeb = New-SPWeb -Url $url -Name $Title -UseParentTopNav  
$NewWeb.ApplyWebTemplate($wtemplate.Name)
```

**Make sure that**

- You have set all the variables like $tempname accurately,
- The $tempname `$wtemplate` and  `$NewWeb` are not null, by calling it as shown below.
- No need to use set `$web again with the new URL site, you should use  the`$NewWeb` directly.

[image]

**[Update]**

The below script will help you to remove an Orphaned Custom Site Template

```
$templateTitle = "TitleOfTemplateToBeZapped"

$site = Get-SPSite http://domain.com/sites/SiteColRoot

$templates = $site.GetWebTemplates(1033) #lcid, 1033 = U.S. 

$badTemplate = $templates | where { $_.Title -eq $templateTitle }

if ($badTemplate -ne $null) {
    # the hidden feature Id is the first part of the template 
    #    name for custom web templates
    $id = $badTemplate.Name.substring(0, $badTemplate.Name.IndexOf("#"))
    $badId = [System.Guid]($id)

    $site.Features.Remove($badId)
    write-output "Template '$templateTitle' has been removed"
} else {
    write-output "No template was found with the title of '$templateTitle'"
}

$site.Dispose()
```

Script Ref: [Use PowerShell to Remove an Orphaned Custom Site Template from SharePoint](https://blog.davidjwise.com/2013/05/06/use-powershell-to-remove-an-orphaned-custom-site-template/)

Comment: I tried, now I get another message: `Exception calling "ApplyWebTemplate" with "1" argument(s): "Value cannot be null.` Does this mean that the template is not found with the given name? Can I check with gui or Designer the `Name` of the templates?

Comment: @vilmarci yes that means $wtemplate is null, one thing I have noted is using $Web instead of the $NewWeb at $Web.ApplyWebTemplate($wtemplate.Name), let me update you with a script that I tried on my side and  worked properly

Comment: @vilmarci do you checked the modified script? please feedback me in case you still face issue!

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback, took some time to move test scripts to prd. So, what I found out is, that I get 2 different error messages: If I template title is correct, the updated script returns `Exception calling "ApplyWebTemplate" with "1" argument(s): "Value cannot be null.`
If the template title is valid, but something unknown goes wrong, I get the `Exception calling "ApplyWebTemplate" with "1" argument(s): "File or arguments not valid for site template 'System.Object[]'.'` error message.

Comment: NP, let me check your updates in my side and feedback!

Comment: So, root cause found, if you have any idea, how to remove the duplicates, please share.

Comment: Check this https://blog.davidjwise.com/2013/05/06/use-powershell-to-remove-an-orphaned-custom-site-template/

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback. I found a workaround, changed my process to use the system name as an input. This is not that user-friendly, but failsafe. But as there's a workaround and I could not reproduce the issue on our dev/uat servers further experimenting on the prd server is denied. Thank you for the help, the issue remains a mistery.